# Process crash on Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to launch an app and I'm seeing a force close of the app. The root cause is not clear since the crash traces are pointing to "libsecuritysdkx-1.2.36.so", which seems to be due to __stack_chk_fail. I'm not sure how to check further. Kindly advice further.

```
--------- beginning of crash
2270  2304 F libc    : stack corruption detected
2270  2304 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 2304 (pool-1-thread-1)
2270  2297 F libc    : stack corruption detected
2270  2297 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 2297 (Thread-218)
191   191 I DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
191   191 I DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'eng/test'
191   191 I DEBUG   : pid: 2270, tid: 2304, name: pool-1-thread-1  >>> com.fanli.android.apps <<<
191   191 I DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------

01-01 05:11:27.347   191   191 I DEBUG   : Abort message: 'stack corruption detected'
01-01 05:11:27.347   191   191 I DEBUG   :     eax 00000000  ebx 000008de  ecx 00000900  edx 00000006
01-01 05:11:27.347   191   191 I DEBUG   :     esi 61d3bdb8  edi 00000002
01-01 05:11:27.347   191   191 I DEBUG   :     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000087  xss 0000007b
01-01 05:11:27.348   191   191 I DEBUG   :     eip 77506cd6  ebp 00000900  esp 61d38bf0  flags 00200206
01-01 05:11:27.348   191   191 I DEBUG   : 
01-01 05:11:27.348   191   191 I DEBUG   : backtrace:
01-01 05:11:27.348   191   191 I DEBUG   :     #00 pc 00085cd6  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+22)
01-01 05:11:27.348   191   191 I DEBUG   :     #01 pc 00031853  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+163)
01-01 05:11:27.348   191   191 I DEBUG   :     #02 pc 00033125  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+37)
01-01 05:11:27.348   191   191 I DEBUG   :     #03 pc 0002b1f5  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+85)
01-01 05:11:27.349   191   191 I DEBUG   :     #04 pc 0002e071  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_fatal+33)
01-01 05:11:27.349   191   191 I DEBUG   :     #05 pc 00083f0d  /system/lib/libc.so (__stack_chk_fail+29)
01-01 05:11:27.349   191   191 I DEBUG   :     #06 pc 0009959b  /data/data/com.fanli.android.apps/files/libsecuritysdkx-1.2.36.so
```

Comment: does your app use ndk classes or anything that would hint towards "direct" interaction with memory?

Comment: app uses native libraries ... crash seen in its library ...but its a third party app whose details are not available with us

Comment: In that case, you might want to contact the 3p native library's developers and report the crash.

Comment: Looks like the app seems to work with Nexus phone but not on DUT ..I am trying to figure out which layer i should be debugging further

Comment: Is Nexus architecture (arm, x86, ...) different from DUT?

Comment: Nexus uses ARM based chiset where as DUT doest use ARM